# Meteor-publish returns more rows then required from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-publications

I have a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "SeGtBvCT7ojF2v5x9",
    "teamId" : "d74JJ9s5k6tijeQaz",
    "userScores" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "6ghphqzx9GFnvKYKY",
            "scores" : 10,
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-04T06:37:06.387Z")
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "56ghp45hqzx9G2dda",
            "scores" : 1,
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-04T06:37:19.105Z")
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "wrr3422fwefx6fFGs",
            "scores" : 4,
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-04T06:37:44.005Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to return 'userScores' for one teamId and current user Id (this.userId). So I made this publish method.

```
Meteor.publish('scoresTeamByUser', function(teamId) {
  return Scores.find(
      { teamId }, 
      { userScores: { $elemMatch: { userId: this.userId } } }
  );
});
```

But in meteor/react app I receive (this.props.receivedScores) the whole document, with all rows in "userScores".

```
export default withTracker(props => {
    const scoresSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('scoresTeamByUser', props.teamId);
    return {
        receivedScores: Scores.findOne(),
        scoresLoaded: scoresSubscription.ready()
    };
})(GiveScores);
```

How to get just data for one team and one user which gave a score? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your query and it works fine and returns only one object of the `userScores` array that matches the `userId`.

You need to use `fields` to filter the fields that you want to publish.

```
Meteor.publish('scoresTeamByUser', function(teamId) {
  return Scores.find(
      { teamId }, 
      { fields: { userScores: { $elemMatch: { userId: this.userId }}} }
  );
});
```

<s>The reason that you are getting all the objects in the `userScores` array is that you must be having another subscription that is publishing the entire record. You can check this by `console.log(Scores.findOne({ props.teamId}))` before subscribing to the `scoresTeamByUser` publication.</s>

So, you have to either find that publication and limit it to publish only the scores of the current user or in your current subscription, you have to filter the data on the client-side query as below.

```
export default withTracker(props => {
    const scoresSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('scoresTeamByUser', props.teamId);
    return {
        receivedScores: Scores.findOne({ teamId: props.teamId }, 
  { userScores: { $elemMatch: { userId: Meteor.userId() } }),
        scoresLoaded: scoresSubscription.ready()
    };
})(GiveScores);
```

Comment: I will try it out! Will come back with results. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi again. I do not publish Scores collection any other places. So I do not understand why it works like this. ??? Any ideas?

Comment: A example like this I find here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/ but why I works in Robo 3T, and does not in Meteor?

Comment: Sorry mate, my bad. Update the answer

Comment: Yes! It was exactly I was looking for. Meteor adds 'fields' before $elemMatch. Now it works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this.

```
Meteor.publish('scoresTeamByUser', function(teamId) {

    const teamScores = Scores.find({ teamId: teamId });

    const userScore = Scores.find(
    {'userScores.userId': this.userId}, {'userScores.$': 1});

    return [teamScores, userScore];
});
```

Comment: Actually I cannot see how it can help.